# Parse JSON Data using Shell Scripting

Tags: bash, shell, sh

How do I parse the values of the string 'key' from the below json data using shell scripting?

```
/Users/local/Documents/testjira:{"expand":"schema","names","startAt":"0","maxResults":"50","total":"2","issues":[{"expand":"operations","editmeta","changelog","transitions","renderedFields","id":"56392","self":"https://website.com/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/50342","key":"SAR-32"},{"expand":"operations","editmeta","changelog","transitions","renderedFields","id":"49799","self":"https://website.com/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/19720","key":"SAR-5"}]}
```

**Example output:** SAR-32, SAR-5 so on..

Comment: Use appropriate `json` parsing tools like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `grep` and `cut` to do this easily:

```
[ttucker@localhost ~]$ cat /tmp/testjira2
{"expand":"schema","names","startAt":"0","maxResults":"50","total":"2","issues":[{"expand":"operations","editmeta","changelog","transitions","renderedFields","id":"56392","self":"https://website.com/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/50342","key":"SAR-32"},{"expand":"operations","editmeta","changelog","transitions","renderedFields","id":"49799","self":"https://website.com/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/19720","key":"SAR-5"}]}

[ttucker@localhost ~]$ grep -o '"key":"[^"]*"' /tmp/testjira2 |cut -d'"' -f4
SAR-32
SAR-5
```

Comment: I used the above command, but it didn't display any output. The command I used "grep -o 'key:[-A-Z0-9]*' /Users/local/Documents/jira | cut -d: -f2"

Comment: What version of `grep` are you using? `grep -V` Also, are you sure that your data matches your sample data?

Comment: Yeah, I am sure the data is same. grep version -- 'grep (GNU grep) 2.20'

Comment: That should be fine. If you take you test data and put it in a file, then run the command on it, does it return results? Also, does it have to be bash? Since it is JSON you could easily load it with Perl or PHP or something ...

Comment: Sorry, I have verified the data one more time.

Comment: {"expand":"schema,names","startAt":0,"maxResults":50,"total":2,"issues":[{"expand":"operations,editmeta,changelog,transitions,renderedFields","id":"56392","self":"https://website.com/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/50342","key":"SAR-32"},{"expand":"operations,editmeta,changelog,transitions,renderedFields","id":"49799","self":"https://website.com/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/19720","key":"SAR-5"}]}

Comment: The key, value pair is in double quotes is the data  which I am trying with. Could you let me know the grep command that would work with above data?

Comment: Ahh... That is why the data was not passing a JSON validator.

Comment: I just added braces to the command `grep -o '"key":"[-A-Z0-9]*"' /Users/local/Documents/jira | cut -d: -f2` And it worked. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer, it is actually easier with the `"` in there. Also, I am going to update your question to include the proper data.

Comment: `grep` and `cut` are not suitable for parsing JSON. You might be able to cobble together a solution for *some* JSON documents, but in general this will not work.

Comment: This is some black magic that worked for me perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming valid JSON like

```
{
    "expand":["schema", "names"],
    "startAt":"0",
    "maxResults":"50",
    "total":"2",
    "issues":[
        {
            "expand":["operations","editmeta","changelog","transitions","renderedFields"],
            "id":"56392",
            "self":"https://website.com/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/50342",
            "key":"SAR-32"
        },
        {
            "expand":["operations","editmeta","changelog","transitions","renderedFields"],
            "id":"49799",
            "self":"https://website.com/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/19720",
            "key":"SAR-5"
        }
    ]
}
```

you can use the following call to `jq`:

```
$ jq -r '.issues[] | .key' tmp.json
SAR-32
SAR-5
```

Answer (score 0):

One may use [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) with [Here Documents](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents), for example:

```
alec@mba ~/project/lnet (master) $ cat /Users/alec/project/lnet/test/rc/05\ Two\ hubs.json
{
  "desc": "This is a configuration file to run the test on all the hubs and leaves that can possibly participate",
  "hubs": { "hub0": "176.37.63.2", "hub1": "10.0.0.10" }
}
alec@mba ~/project/lnet (master) $ runAll() {
>   local conf="$HOME/project/lnet/$1"
>   echo "runAll: using configuration file $conf"
>   local output=$(node <<-EOF_JS
>     const conf = require("$conf")
>     console.log('hub0="' + conf.hubs.hub0 + '"')
> EOF_JS
> )
>   eval "$output"; echo "$hub0"
> }
alec@mba ~/project/lnet (master) $ runAll test/rc/05\ Two\ hubs.json
runAll: using configuration file /Users/alec/project/lnet/test/rc/05 Two hubs.json
176.37.63.2
alec@mba ~/project/lnet (master) $
```